# How to get a unique set of values for a given field of array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on integrating Solr search with a RoR app. The solr returns docs which have a field `productTaxonomyName`.

In the controller corresponding to search I retrieve docs from solr and push them into a `@products` array. I want to get the set of unique values of the `productTaxonomyName` field in a variable within the controller. How can I do that.

Will this work:

```
@taxons = @products.map {|p| p.productTaxonomyName }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@taxons = @products.map(&:productTaxonomyName).compact.uniq
```

Btw, why dont you get them right from Solr.